# React JS : Logging the array items in the console

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, console, console.log

I have an array of objects, where I need to view each item inside the object one by one and their properties inside the object. When I tried to view the objects by using *console.log(listItems);* in the code and by giving inspect in Google Chrome, in the console tab I get ;

```
listofItems: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] ...
```

But what I need is to see the attributes and properties inside the Items and the respective values assigned to them in the array, which contains multiple objects.
I have already tried out

`console.log(JSON.stringify(listItems));`

but ended up getting error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON --> 
   starting at object with constructor 'FiberNode' | property 'stateNode' -> ...
```

consider the code snippet below:

```js
render() {
        let { items } = this.props;
        let listItems = items.map( (item) => {
            return (
                    <TodoItem text={item.text} 
                       ID={item.key} 
                       isComplete={item.completedItem} 
                       onDelete={this.props.onDelete} 
                       onEdit={this.props.onEdit} 
                       handleComplete={this.props.handleComplete}/>
            );
        });
        console.log("listofItems: " + listItems);
....
```

Is there any way I could view the properties and the values assigned in each object inside the array...?

Comment: Consider appending some code to your post (preferably, along with your source data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use comma instead of +.

```
console.log("listofItems: ",  listItems);
```

This way javascript wont try to convert it to string, and chrome console would let you expand your array of objects